# Hover of drop down text colour not been applied

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I made a fixed navigation bar but can't seem to determine why when you hover on the "Main Menu" and then hover the sub menu, the text of "Main Menu" doesn't change color?

```
#nav-top > ul > li > a:hover, .nav-top-menu-button:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

JSFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/owboLy2s/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/owboLy2s/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `#nav-top > ul > li:hover > a, .nav-top-menu-button:hover` instead of `#nav-top > ul > li > a:hover, .nav-top-menu-button:hover`. So,change is  `:hover` should be moved one step up. Otherwise, only your `<a href=''>Menu</a>` code will trigger color change.

Answer (score 0):

```
li.nav-top-menu-button:hover a{
   color:#000!important;
}
```

This should work. 
It targets your main `li` that contains the  "Menu" link. Since the drop-down menu is still inside that `li` you will still be hovering it when selection a sub-link. The `!important` just says that it takes precedence over any other styling.